# Any "classic" setup page in Lightning Experience opens in new browser tab

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, salesforce, cross-domain

I have been having a very odd problem in all Salesforce orgs, but only when using Chrome.

If I go to Setup, and click on a "classic" setup link, like "users", instead of opening it in the iframe within lightning, it attempts to open it in a new browser tab.  The page renders, but none of the links or javascript do anything.

I have seen advice that says to avoid a plugin called "Ghostery" but I am not using that, and have turned off other browser extensions but nothing works.  This is not happening for anyone else I know using chrome and salesforce, which leads me to believe it is some Chrome configuration setting, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: ad blocker? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217300/chrome-salesforce-lightning-setup-pages-opens-as-new-tab

Comment: No, I removed my adblocker after seeing the same post.  But it feels somehow related to this